# How might I write $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ continuity proofs if I am good at writing proofs with the topological defintion?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Being that it is the end of the semester I have an Analysis final coming up in a few days.  On previous tests my professor has asked for a proof that a certain function was continuous *explicitly* requiring that the proof use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ method of continuity.

The thing is, like many students, I *really* don't like the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ method. I much prefer to prove that the pre-image of every open set on the domain is open, I find it more intuitive and it was what I was using for a while before questions requiring the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ method started popping up.

In a proof by example, [Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39174/hagen-von-eitzen) pointed out that there are certainly many cases where it is a better idea to use $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs over the topological ones.  However there are still cases where I find it easier to the topological definition.

My question is it there some way I could convert a proof using the pre-image of open sets definition to a $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ format?  Or use my intuitions of one proof method to generate proofs in the other?  My main issue with rewriting my proofs is that the pre-image definition deals with continuity of an interval rather than the continuity of a single point, while the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definiton defines continuity at a single point.

I understand that $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs are an important skill to have, and that my professor probably has good intentions in requiring them. I plan to practice my $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ skills before the test, but I still feel nervous I might blank on the test and I would like to have a back-up plan for these types of questions.

Comment: Does it help to realize that the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition is simply the specialization of the open pre-image of open sets definition to a metric topology?  Given an epsilon-ball in the image, one finds a delta-ball in the preimage such that....

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would write a pre-image-of-open-is-open proof of, say, the continuity of $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto x^3+7x$?

Comment: Aah! the curse of topology... it looks deceptively simple!  As von Eitzen commented, how else to prove that $x^3+7x$ (or $x^3-7x$) is continuous without some sort of $\epsilon-\delta$ proof?

Comment: @MMS You can use theorems such as the sum and products of continuous functions are continuous. It only remains to prove that $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto 7$ are continuous.

Comment: I noticed that often people were hating $\epsilon-\delta$ because they were puzzled about foreseeing in advance in how much that have to cut their $\epsilon$ or how much precise they need their $\delta$ so that in the end they get $|foo-bar|<\epsilon$. As soon as you realize though that rough majorations suffice and you need only $|foo-bar|<K\epsilon$ for some constant $K$ then the pressure on this kind of proofs just goes poof. Maybe did you experienced this kind of blocking towards the $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs.

Comment: One approach, in the "technically correct is the best kind of correct" vein, would be to begin your final by proving the equivalency of the two approaches when working on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology, and then cite this as a lemma for the rest of the proofs. EDIT: Meant to be "tongue in cheek"---not necessarily recommended, depending on the professor's tempermant

Comment: @erfink I think your comment is a bit tongue in cheek, but I don't really think that would be considered acceptable.  I've tried to do similar things in the past.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen As perhaps indicated by the time gap, I find your example very hard to do in the language of a topological proof, it seems that particular example is much better to do in the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ method.  It is certainly true that the topological proof method is no silver bullet, but there are still many functions I would prefer to prove using the topological method.

Comment: @Gribouillis And how do you prove that the product of two continuous functions is continuous? With an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, possibly in disguise of open sets $U,V$. The point is that the two are essentially the same; one cannot claim to 'understand' a topology proof but not an $\epsilon-\delta$ one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest proofs are the ones that use sequential continuity, that is to say $f$ is continuous if and only if
$$\lim x_n = a \quad\Longrightarrow\quad  \lim f(x_n) = f(a)$$

These proofs are easy to design and they are excellent starting point to create a $\epsilon - \delta$ proof.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up, however I don't really think that this answers the question I asked.  This is a way of generating an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof, but doesn't concern itself at all with the topological definition.

Comment: As @hardmath pointed out, if you are able to prove that the preimage of any open set $U$ is open, then you are able to prove that the preimage of $B(f(a), \varepsilon)$ is open, then you are able to prove that $f^{-1}(B(f(a), \varepsilon))$ contains a non empty ball $B(a, \delta)$, then you are able to give a $\epsilon -\delta$ proof. We need you to give  concrete examples to go farther.